# Spring boot, OAuth2.0, Zuul authentication problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies, oauth-2.0, microservices

I have been trying to build an application with Zuul, Eureka and Spring boot and recently I decided to attempt the login. As a reminder, I have already configured the authentication service (using OAuth 2.0) and I can successfully authenticate using CURL. I can also make get petitions to other microservices that have protected resources (again only with CURL because I can inject the token in the authentication header). My concern is that I want to do this with Zuul as a gateway.

[image]

Briefly the process that I follow based on above the diagram is the following:

1) From the web explorer, I enter to the gateway IP.

2) The gateway is configured in the following way, hence, it redirects to the authorization server allocated in a different computer.

```
    authentication:
        path: /proxy/authentication/**
        serviceId: AuthenticationMicroservice
        stripPrefix: false
```

```
    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/proxy/authentication/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated();

        // This is in charge of redirecting to the login index in the authentication server in case
        // you are not logged in.
        AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = (request, response, authException) -> response.sendRedirect("/proxy/authentication/login");
        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
    }
```

3) The /login in the authorization service is the default Spring boot, JWT, security login index

[image]

4) I type the details that I have already configured, click login but nothing happens. Zuul doesn't redirect to the UI microservice (That is not listed in the diagram), I feel that there is no cookie generated and forwarded back to Zuul so Zuul can forward it back to the Web explorer and hence, there is no way to validate that cookie.

I would appreciate if you could solve a few questions I have at the moment:

1) Using CURL for the authentication server url: `localhost:9096/oauth/token\?grant_type=password\&username=test\&password=secret`. Does it generates a cookie? I think it doesn't, the only thing I get in response is a JSON that represents the token. Does that means that I need to read that JSON and encode it in a cookie? Do I need a cookie or is there any other ways to do this? How can I do that with Zuul?

2) How can I validate that cookie from Zuul?

3) Do I need to create the cookie in the Zuul server? Or in the Authorization Server?

4) How can I validate that cookie **from another microservice** such as the edge microservice?

5) How can I generate a new token after the old token has been discarded? (because of the time stamp), **Where** do I generate that new token? (Within **Zuul**? Do I have to make a call to the **authentication server**?), How can I persist that new token as a cookie?

6) How can I handle cases where the timestamp has been elapsed from within microservices, for example:
When I validate the token in **edge microservice** I have 2 more seconds, then, after I pass the token to the **microservice** it has no remaining time. I think one solution can be to create another token that will be used merely within microservices? Is there another approaches to this?

7) I know that I can add more payload to the JWT, for example, if I want to add the user id, how would I proceed to do it? Since the certificate is signed, will I have issues with people changing their client id?

**AuthorizationServerCode**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;

    private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration(final DataSource dataSource, final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                            final SecurityProperties securityProperties) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
    }

    /**
     * Reads data from the tokens themselves.
     * Not really a store since it never persists anything and
     * it uses the JwtAccessTokenConverter to generate and read the tokens.
     */
    @Bean
    TokenStore tokenStore() {
        if (tokenStore == null) {
            tokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }
        return tokenStore;
    }

    /**
     * The DefaultTokenServices uses the TokenStore to persist the tokens.
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(final TokenStore tokenStore,
                                              final ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        return tokenServices;
    }

    /**
     * Uses the self-signed certificate to sign the generated tokens.
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        if (jwtAccessTokenConverter != null) {
            return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
        }

        JwtProperties jwtProperties = securityProperties.getJwt();
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPair(jwtProperties, keyStoreKeyFactory(jwtProperties));

        jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
                .tokenStore(new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter()));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder).tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    private KeyPair keyPair(JwtProperties jwtProperties, KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory) {
        return keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(jwtProperties.getKeyPairAlias(), jwtProperties.getKeyPairPassword().toCharArray());
    }

    private KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory(JwtProperties jwtProperties) {
        return new KeyStoreKeyFactory(jwtProperties.getKeyStore(), jwtProperties.getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
    }
}
```

```
package com.training.inmedia.authenticationservice.configuration;

import com.training.inmedia.authenticationservice.authentication.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfiguration(final UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    /**
     * This bean is required to be injected into the AuthorizationServerConfiguration.
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        if (passwordEncoder == null) {
            passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        }
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * This bean is required to be injected into the AuthorizationServerConfiguration.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you may point most of your questions on this link : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-zuul-oauth-jwt

Comment: I solved this sometime ago. Thanks for your answer tho! If anyone wants my approach, let me know.

Comment: please do share how you fixed it, as I am facing the same problem

Comment: @AlexanderMladzhov Briefly explaining you need to tell Zuul to let it pass a cookie downstream (If you pass it through a cookie) you configure this with the Zuul property sensitiveHeaders.
Answer 1) We ended up not using Oauth2.0 but if im not mistake you get the JWT as a string and then encode it in a cookie and set it to the client.

2) You need to use filters to validate within Zuul that the JWT is valid

3) It depends in your needs

Comment: @AlexanderMladzhov


4) Esentially a JWT is something you can validate from anywhere, so it's up to you if you need to validate it within any microservice, it is about validating the correctness and expiration of the JWT. You don't need to make any calls to any other place.

I think these answers most of my questions, if you have any doubts let me know I can chat with you directly and give you a hand.